# Firebase Authentication: signInAnonymously then signInWithCustomToken

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I use Firebase Authentication for a React Native project

React-native: 0.44.2
Firebase: 4.1.1

Initially I'm using signInAnonymously then I retrieve the token.
After I use the token for authentications (signInWithCustomToken) but I always have auth/invalid-custom-token

Does someone have an idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you `signInAnonymously`, you are already signed in and the ID token is not a custom token. You can't sign in with that.
If you want to make sure the session is maintained the next time the app is restarted, use:

`firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
   if (user) {
     // User signed in. firebase.auth().currentUser is not null.
   } else {
     // No user signed in.
   }
 })`